# Dynamic radius on pie-chart, how to make a on-click function work on a transformation

Tags: echarts

In my pie-chart I have an on-click function that changes values and reloads data.
Changing the radius of the pie chart to the value of a source works (radiusvalue= datafilter[2].source[0][0]), How can I change the radius to a transformation ( in my case 'datafilter[3])

(`codepen:`https://codepen.io/slindersAmsterdam/pen/BaOZZpR)

Comment: Some code formatting would improve the readability of your question.

Comment: thanks, I adjusted it, hope it helps